# Combining pins of a GX-12/GX-16 (aviation) connector

Tags: current, connector

I'm intending to use LED strips and use GX-12 or GX-16 connectors.
Depending on the number of pins and GX-12 or GX-16 type there is a max current allowed (liked 3A).
Can I safely combine two or three pins to get 10A (for the VCC and GND connection to the led strip(s), assuming the current will be (kind of) evenly split between the two or three pins?
(so when I would use an 8 pin connector, to get 9A when I use 3 pins for VCC and 3 pins for GND).

As additional question, does it matter if I connect the 4 or 6 pins to two separate LED strips (of different sizes)? (I assume not).

Comment: Those connectors from PRC are nasty, wrong made. It's almost impossible to correctly solder wires on it. Get a better one, also how would you split a single wire to three wires? For 3/4 pin there are cheap Harting HA(N) clones with metal casing /w cable gland.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič I thought those GX connectors were kind of standard... but I will check for 3/4 pins Harting connectors as well. I don't meant to split them, just to solder one wire to 3 pins, and at the other end, 2 wires (for 2 led strips) on the 3 pins (e.g. for GND).

Comment: I bought a soldering station from Ali, it has a GX-12 conn and 5 tinny wires, let's say 0.4 mm^2. The solder cups aren't cups at all, they have no depth and all are oriented in one direction, not circular. In few words , anything they could do wrong, they did. The final look is horrible, I put a sleeve so that I can't see the mess. I suggest you to look for an alternative.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič Thanks for the explanation ... I couldn't find Harting HA(N) clones yet but I will check into it.